# Regex.Replace - skip strings which are part of a longer string

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I need to replace a list of numeric strings in a text file. However, if the string is part of another numeric string it should not be replaced:
String to be replaced: 111111
Replacement string: MASKED

```
Text file:
111111
 111111.text text
text text111111 text text
a111111
2111111
111111a
1111112
a111111a

Expected result:
MASKED
 MASKED.text text
text textMASKED text text
aMASKED
2111111 -> Character 2 prevents masking
MASKEDa
1111112 -> Character 2 prevents masking
aMASKEDa
```

This is my code:

```
inputText = Regex.Replace(inputText, "(?<![0-9])" + stringToMask + "(?<![0-9])", "####MASKED####");
```

This code just skips everything and doesn't perform any masking.

Comment: Shouldn't the second (?<![0-9]) be (?![0-9]) - a negative look ahead?

Comment: what sh54 said. He deserves the mark :)

Comment: @Henk, no you can't. `\D` would be `[^0-9]`. The `!` belongs to the look behind assertion `(?<! ...)`.

Comment: sh54 - this worked. I'd be happy to select your answer if you create it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MatchEvaluator http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-replace to perform replace by condition. To decide preform replace or not you can add first and last letter to match pattern, split string by this pattern and analyze first and last symbols.

Comment: also add Regexp.Escape to you pattern, it can contain special symbols inside

Comment: I was looking into this because I am interested in adding some more validations to Replace. I'd like to have a list of predefined strings who's presence will suppress the replace action. For example, in string "amount=111111", having 'amount=' should stop the match. I looked at the example you posted and a few others and didn't understand how it can be done. The delegate only takes the match, so it can't check what's coming before it.

Comment: use Regex.Replace(inputText, ".?" + stringToMask + ".?", "####MASKED####"); You will get match that you need with 1 extra symbol in the begging and in the end. Than you can split string by 11111, first item will be first symbol, second - last. When you will finish parsing you should add first and last symbol to replaced string.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it means I can't use it for the purpose I explained above.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, the following regex should work:

```
(?<!\d)111111(?!\d)
```

It uses both a [negative lookbehind assertion and a negative lookahead assertion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx).

Here is [a working example](https://regex101.com/r/tS8oN5/2).

Output:

```
MASKED
 MASKED.text text
text textMASKED text text
aMASKED
2111111
MASKEDa
1111112
aMASKEDa
```